# Any SEO penalty for creating a new website and having no content for years?

Tags: seo, domains, content, penalty

I have a domain with hosting (supposed to be a blog) which has been live for 2 years with zero posts. I finally have created the content for it.

Is it wise to post to the same website or should I buy a new domain? Is there any SEO penalty for leaving the site without content for so long?

Answer (score 4):

You won't have any SEO penalty as Search Engines will see a brand new website.

On the contrary, the domain age and registration length may be a good factor for SEO if it has never been blacklisted.